# SQLite text type

Tags: sqlite, text, types

I have a trouble when using SQLite database with datatype text.

When I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM prob_tokens where (token like 'c%');
```

One of those results returned:
    id: 1130, token: có, prob: 0.011
But, when I type this:

```
SELECT * FROM prob_tokens where (token like 'có');
```

0 Rows returned
People, any helps please?

Comment: `like` without wildcards is basically just an `=` test. try `like 'có%'`. if that returns data, then your token field contains MORE than just `có`.

Comment: Do you have any other examples of data in your token field?

Comment: first of all, thank you very for your response my question. I try `like 'có%'` and then no result, but when I try `like 'co%'` then It returns the row that contains 'có'. Any help, please?